# MongoDB Error in inserting documents, how do I resolve it?

Tags: mongodb

I have been trying to import a JSON file into mongoDB via command prompt, but I get an output that says error inserting documents.

```
C:\Users\chery\Documents\NUS Y2 Sem 1 Modules\BT2102\Tutorials>mongoimport --db school --collection students students.json
2018-11-07T15:37:30.974+0800    connected to: localhost
2018-11-07T15:37:31.210+0800    num failures: 50
2018-11-07T15:37:31.211+0800    error inserting documents: multiple errors in bulk operation:
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 2 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 3 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 4 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 5 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 1 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 0 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 6 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 7 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 10 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 8 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 12 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 13 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 11 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 14 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 15 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 16 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 17 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 18 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 9 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 19 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 20 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 23 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 24 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 22 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 26 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 25 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 27 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 29 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 28 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 21 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 30 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 31 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 33 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 35 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 34 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 36 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 37 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 38 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 32 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 40 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 39 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 41 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 43 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 44 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 46 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 47 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 42 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 45 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 48 }
  - E11000 duplicate key error collection: school.students index: _id_ dup key: { : 49 }

2018-11-07T15:37:31.211+0800    imported 0 documents
```

May I know what is the issue here and how do I rectify the error?

I would really appreciate any help out there!

Comment: You are trying to insert documents with an `_id` that already exists. Depending on your application you may want to update that existing document instead, or maybe set a different `_id`. It is also possible that you are setting `_id` to something you did not really intend to -- it looks weird in the error message. Double-check how the document looks.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, and adding on top of what @Thilo already mentions in the comment above, you should avoid using custom values in the "_id" field and let MongoDB generate ObjectIds for you. In other words, do not set _id to anything in your documents if at all possible, that will improve performance and guarantee uniqueness (for that particular key).

Comment: You can try and import into a different collection and work with that collection if this is just a tutorial or drop the existing collection first and then import again if the existing data is not needed